# How to avoid axis inversion by DataRange when used in Arrayplot?

Tags: plotting

Working on Mathematica 11.3, I find that the vertical axis (more precisely its ticks) is reversed by `DataRange` which should not happen, e.g.

```
nmax = 100;
ArrayPlot[Table[x + y, {x, 0, nmax}, {y, 0, nmax}], PlotLegends -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
ArrayPlot[Table[x + y, {x, 0, nmax}, {y, 0, nmax}], PlotLegends -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> {{0, nmax}, {0, nmax}}]
```

Resulting in

[image: ArrayPlot w/o manual DataRange]

[image: ArrayPlot w/ manual DataRange]

I want a plot like in the first picture but with arbitrarily chosen `DataRange` and do not want to have the data reversed along the vertical direction (as in `ListDensityPlot`). Both axes should start at the top left corner. I found a workaround using manual setting of frame ticks but that is not nice. Is their a simple solution?

Comment: I also think this shouldn't happen. You could use `Take` to select which data range you want in this case.

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Sorry, could you give an example of how you would use `Take` in this context?

Comment: ‘Take[Table[x+y.....],{{0,nmax},{0,nmax}}]’?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Ah,ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-intuitive, but expected behavior. It just comes down to how do you interpret `DataRange`. See the additional option `DataReversed`

```
ArrayPlot[Table[x + y, {x, 0, nmax}, {y, 0, nmax}], 
 PlotLegends -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 DataRange -> {{0, nmax}, {0, nmax}}, DataReversed -> True]
ArrayPlot[Reverse@Table[x + y, {x, 0, nmax}, {y, 0, nmax}], 
 PlotLegends -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 DataRange -> {{0, nmax}, {0, nmax}}, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

The underling reason is, that usually matrix indexes start from top left, while plot coordinates from left bottom. The function named `ArrayPlot` has to bring these two worlds together.

Comment: Ahhh... first I misunderstood you answer. You reversed both using an option of `ArrayPlot` and the data itself. Seems to work. Thanks.